Why can the first-order correction to the $n$th wavefunction be expressed as a sum of unpertubed wavefunctions?
The following expression is confusing me:
$$\psi_n^{1} = \sum_{m\neq n}c^{(n)}_{m}\psi_{m}^{0}. $$
In the above expression, $\psi_n^{1}$ represents the first-order correction to the wavefunction, $c$ is some arbitrary constant, and $\psi_{m}^{0}$, represents the unperturbed eigenfunctions.
Now, I understand that the unperturbed eigenfunctions constitute a complete set (basis), so in general any function can be constructed from linear combinations of them, but that's about it. I do not understand why there is a summation taking place over $m$ and $n$ and additionally why it is necessary to exclude the case where $m\neq n$.

The summation is over $m$. You have to exclude $m=n$ because if you include it, the contribution from the $m=n$ part can be absorbed into the zeroth order eigenfunction i.e. $\psi^0_n$, so that you will only get a redefinition of expansion coefficients.

To clarify, this is a double summation over $m$ and $n$ right? With $n$ representing an indices of $c$

It's a single summation.

My understanding was that any summation with $a \neq b$ is a summation of every possible pair of $a$ and $b$, but excluding the cases where $a$ and $b$ are equal?

Any rule you learned like that must always take a back seat to common sense. How can something depending on $n$ be equal to something that sums over all $n$?

I agree that the notation is confusing. You could always fix it with an unambiguous Dirac delta like $\sum_a x(1-\delta^a_b)$ but that might not be desirable. In any case yes this is a single summation over all values of $a$ except for $b$.

As here we want to solve the wavefunctions for a perturbed system, what perturbation does is that it mixes up the unperturbed states as non-diagonal terms in the Hamiltonian is non-zero. Here, the summation is over $m$, which is a different index than $n$. We are not adding m=n again because we already have that state in the zeroth order. Nevertheless, if you try to sum the terms when $m = n$, the state won't be normalised.
There is a nice discussion about this in J.J. Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics.
